# Group by JSON data in Node

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, underscore.js-templating

In my nodeJs code I am fetching some records from database. I am getting the data as JSON as below:

```
"Data": [{
    "id": 1,
    "color": "blue",
    "model_name": "ford",
    "year": 2016
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "color": "blue",
    "model_name": "Maruti",
    "year": 2016
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "color": "red",
    "model_name": "Fiat",
    "year": 2016
}, {
    "id": 4,
    "color": "red",
    "model_name": "tata",
    "year": 2016
}]
```

What I want is something like the following JSON:

```
"Data": [{
    "color": "blue",
    car: [{
        "id": 1,
        "color": "blue",
        "model_name": "ford",
        "year": 2016
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "color": "blue",
        "model_name": "Maruti",
        "year": 2016
    }]
}, {
    "color": "red",
    car: [{
        "id": 3,
        "color": "red",
        "model_name": "Fiat",
        "year": 2016
    }, {
        "id": 4,
        "color": "red",
        "model_name": "tata",
        "year": 2016
    }]
}]
```

I could have achieved this using 'groupBy' method of underscore JS by using the code below:

```
var groupedData = _.groupBy(rows, f=>{return f.color});
```

However the output becomes:

```
"Data": [{
    "blue": [{
        "id": 1,
        "color": "blue",
        "model_name": "ford",
        "year": 2016
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "color": "blue",
        "model_name": "Maruti",
        "year": 2016
    }]
}, {

    "red": [{
        "id": 3,
        "color": "red",
        "model_name": "Fiat",
        "year": 2016
    }, {
        "id": 4,
        "color": "red",
        "model_name": "tata",
        "year": 2016
    }]
}]
```

Here the problem is that the color name is itself the key. I want to have "color": "blue" , in this format but in a group by way.

Comment: None of that is standard JSON. It will fail to validate. Also, you have an un-quoted key for `Data[0].car` in your second "JSON" example.

Answer (score 9):

One other straightforward way of this by pure ES6 code.

```js
var data = [
{
  "id": 1,
  "color": "blue",
  "model_name": "ford",
  "year": 2016
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "color": "blue",
  "model_name": "Maruti",
  "year": 2016
},
{
  "id": 3,
  "color": "red",
  "model_name": "Fiat",
  "year": 2016
},
{
  "id": 4,
  "color": "red",
  "model_name": "tata",
  "year": 2016
}],
    hash = data.reduce((p,c) => (p[c.color] ? p[c.color].push(c) : p[c.color] = [c],p) ,{}),
 newData = Object.keys(hash).map(k => ({color: k, car: hash[k]}));
console.log(newData);
```

Comment: its a very good answer but i'd like to add that "minifying" the code (using single letters for variables and params, ternaries, etc) are VERY confusing and adds nothing to the explanation nor comprehension of the answer. I hope i do not offend you. Thanks anyway for helping him and others!

Comment: @Caio Wilson In `.reduce()` `p` and `c` are common choice for previous and current but you may be right. It's my laziness.

Comment: I know, but just like res, req, func, foo and bar, I tend to avoid for the sake of comprehension. Thanks for the answer though, works like a charm, i just make it a little more modular and as a function.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a short answer using lodash:

```
_(Data)
    .groupBy((elem) => elem.color)
    .map((vals, key) => ({color: key, car: vals}))
    .value()
```

If you find that confusing, you can see it as:

```
_.map(
    _.groupBy(Data, elem => elem.color), 
    (vals, key) => {
        return {color: key, car: vals}
    }
)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Here, I made a little `groupBy` function that works in your case. In order to keep it general-purpose, I replaced the "car" key name by "items" :

```
function groupBy(key, array) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var added = false;
    for (var j = 0; j < result.length; j++) {
      if (result[j][key] == array[i][key]) {
        result[j].items.push(array[i]);
        added = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (!added) {
      var entry = {items: []};
      entry[key] = array[i][key];
      entry.items.push(array[i]);
      result.push(entry);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Now if

```
var data = [{
    "id": 1,
    "color": "blue",
    "model_name": "ford",
    "year": 2016
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "color": "blue",
    "model_name": "Maruti",
    "year": 2016
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "color": "red",
    "model_name": "Fiat",
    "year": 2016
}, {
    "id": 4,
    "color": "red",
    "model_name": "tata",
    "year": 2016
}]
```

Then

```
groupBy("color", data);
```

Should give you expected results:

```
[
  {
    "color": "blue",
    "items": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "color": "blue",
        "model_name": "ford",
        "year": 2016
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "color": "blue",
        "model_name": "Maruti",
        "year": 2016
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "color": "red",
    "items": [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "color": "red",
        "model_name": "Fiat",
        "year": 2016
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "color": "red",
        "model_name": "tata",
        "year": 2016
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const data = [
{
  "id": 1,
  "color": "blue",
  "model_name": "ford",
  "year": 2016
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "color": "blue",
  "model_name": "Maruti",
  "year": 2016
},
{
  "id": 3,
  "color": "red",
  "model_name": "Fiat",
  "year": 2016
},
{
  "id": 4,
  "color": "red",
  "model_name": "tata",
  "year": 2016
}
];

const sorted = data.reduce((result, car) => {
    const a = result.find(({color}) => color === car.color);
    a ? a.car.push(car) : result.push({color: car.color, car: [car]});
    return result;
}, []);

console.log(sorted);
```